# Is there an alternate/better way to do this simple logic in java?

Tags: java

I have a method, say method1(), that takes a while to run. During it's execution, if there is another call to method1(), it should be ignored. I have, roughly, something like this

```
    boolean mFlag = false;

    void method1()
    {
        if(!mFlag)
        {
           mFlag=true;

           // do Stuff

          mFlag=false;
        }
    }
```

This works. But I was wondering if there is a better way to do this preferably not involving any flags.

Comment: This is good. It's how it's usually done.

Comment: Are you trying to solve the problem of multiple threads executing the same method at once, or the problem of the method (perhaps indirectly) calling itself?

Comment: @Anon the method indirectly calling itself.

Comment: @Bala the solution I provided initially does not actually prevent that.  The *reentrant* part of the lack ;)

Comment: @Affe found isHeldByCurrentThread() in ReentrantLock. That should help, right?

Comment: Yup, that works fine too, brain was stuck in second gear or something when I used getHoldCount() instead :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should really be using something from java.util.concurrent.locks  Your example isn't quite strictly correct, that boolean needs to be volatile.

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    void method1()
    {
        if(lock.tryLock())
        {
           try {
             if (!(lock.getHoldCount() > 1)) {
               //do Some Stuff
             }
          } finally {
            lock.unlock();
          }
        }
    }
```

Edited to handle skipping execution on reentrance as inidicated in your comment.  Unfortunatly there isn't really a great way to do that with the built in library, as it's a bit of an odd usecase, but I still think using the built in library is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to guard against re-entry from the same thread or multiple threads accessing at the same time.

Assuming multi-threaded access, the light approach is to use `java.util.concurrent.atomic`. No  need for anything as "heavy" as a lock (provided there are not further requirements).

Assuming no-reentry from the same method:

```
private final AtomicBoolean inMethod = new AtomicBoolean();

void method1() {
    if (inMethod.compareAndSet(true, false)) { // Alternatively getAndSet
        try {
            // do Stuff
        } finally {
            inMethod.set(false); // Need to cover exception case!
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to allow reentry within the same thread, then it gets messy enough to use locks:

```
private final AtomicReference<Thread> inMethod = new AtomicReference<Thread>();

void method1() {
    final Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
    final Thread old = inMethod.get();
    if (
        old == current || // We already have it.
        inMethod.compareAndSet(null, current) // Acquired it.
    ) {
        try {
            // do Stuff
        } finally {
            inMethod.set(old); // Could optimise for no change.
        }
    }
}
```

Could use the Execute Around idiom for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use synchronized methods

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: my understanding is that with synchronized methods,  the second call would be blocked until the first call is done and then execute the second call. but my requirement is for the second call to be ignored.

Comment: @Bala: that is correct. You would need to synchronize while setting your flag as above. You would also need to do double checked locking : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking  The way you have it above would be prone to synchronization problems while setting and checking the flag. Or... you can use the Lock class as Affe suggested. :)

Comment: @Bala - given what you say in the comments to your question, please note that a second call *from a different thread* would be blocked.  If somehow, your method was called recursively (directly or indirectly) from the same thread, the second call *from the same thread*  would *not* block.